# Where is the "Service Principal Permissions Management Page"?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph

I'm prototyping a new web part using [MSGraphClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph) and the new `webApiPermissionRequests` section in the `package-solution.json`.

When deploying the SharePoint Framework Client Side solution to the app catalog the following dialog is shown:

[image]

> Please go to the Service Principal Permissions Management Page to
>   approve pending permissions.

Where the heck is this *Service Principal Permissions Management Page*?

(The tenant is in targeted release mode.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact URL of the page is as below:

```
https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/
AdminHome.aspx#/webApiPermissionManagement
```

It is available as part of the new Admin center.

You should click on Try the Preview link from your classic SharePoint admin center page.

[image]

After that, it will open up the new admin center, where you can click the `API management` link to approve the permissions.

[image]